# When and why to use mustache templates

Tags: javascript, templates, express, mustache

What is the use case for mustache templates?

What benefit do they have over something like jade/coffeekup in express?

How does mustache template compilation help?

Cant seem to find a good answer for these basic questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Template engine chooser:  http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242) Sorry.

Comment: When? [Movember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movember) of course...sorry. I couldn't resist... =/

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL im not looking for a recommendation though.. i'm trying to find out why it exists and why id use it..

Comment: @dbaseman thanks for the link - its a start on my path for figuring this out. cheers